# Unable to kill Python Script

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want my script to stop when all the commands in my sendShell function finishes executing all the commands in my commandfactory list.  I can successfully shut my transport connection, but the script seems to hang after all the commands are ran and the transport connection closes.  Can anyone help me find a way to stop my script when all the commands are finished executing and the transport session closes?

I tried to kill the script by adding while not self.transport.close() to my output loop.

```
def process(self):
            while not self.transport.close(): #Kill script here !!!
                # Print data when available
                if self.shell != None and self.shell.recv_ready():
                    alldata = self.shell.recv(1024)
                    while self.shell.recv_ready():
                        alldata += self.shell.recv(1024)
                    strdata = alldata.decode("utf8")
                    strdata.rstrip("\r\n")
                    print(strdata, end = ""),
```

**Code:**

```
import threading, paramiko, re, os

class ssh:
    shell = None
    client = None
    transport = None


    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        print("Connecting to server on ip", str(address) + ".")
        self.client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((address, 22))
        self.transport.connect(username=username, password=password)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def closeConnection(self):
        if(self.client != None):
            self.client.close()
            self.transport.close()

    def openShell(self):
        self.shell = self.client.invoke_shell()

    def sendShell(self):
        self.commandfactory = []
        print("\nWelcome to Command Factory. Enter Commands you want to execute.\nType \"done\" when you are finished:")
        while not re.search(r"done.*", str(self.commandfactory)):
            self.commandfactory.append(input(":"))
            if self.commandfactory[-1] == "done":
                del self.commandfactory[-1]
                break

        print ("Here are the commands you're going to execute:\n" + str(self.commandfactory))
        if(self.shell):
            self.shell.send("enable" + "\n")
            self.shell.send("ilovebeer" + "\n")
            self.shell.send("term len 0" + "\n")
            for cmdcnt in range(0,len(self.commandfactory)):
                self.shell.send(self.commandfactory[cmdcnt] + "\n")
            self.shell.send("exit" + "\n")
            self.shell.transport.close()

        else:
            print("Shell not opened.")

    def process(self):
#         global connection
        while not self.transport.close():
            # Print data when available
            if self.shell != None and self.shell.recv_ready():
                alldata = self.shell.recv(1024)
                while self.shell.recv_ready():
                    alldata += self.shell.recv(1024)
                strdata = alldata.decode("utf8")
                strdata.rstrip("\r\n")
                print(strdata, end = ""),

sshUsername = "xxxxx"
sshPassword = "xxxxxxx"
sshServer = "xxxxxxxx"

connection = ssh(sshServer, sshUsername, sshPassword)
connection.openShell()

while True:
    connection.sendShell()
```

Comment: I hope those aren't real login credentials you posted here?

Comment: @benten,
they are logins for a closed off VM test router, but I removed just in case someone gets nervous :)

Comment: Remove the `while True:`.

Comment: @Klaus,
I've tried that, but I don't know what to replace it with.  I've tried to tie it to connection.transport.close(), but that didn't kill the script.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old... but I was trying to figure out the same thing for a while.

Like one of the other comments said... remove "while True:" at the bottom.

Also, your "global connection" line is commented out.  Un-comment that. and add this to the bottom of your script to close the connection.

connection.closeConnection(connection)